# Odd use of 'in the'?

Tags: grammaticality

> On this view the law’s goal should be to make a rule that gets the
>   owner of the ballpark to think the way a single owner would when he decides
>   what precautions to take. Making him pay for every window broken
>   by his baseballs (whether or not he builds a fence) might do the trick;
>   that would be known as strict liability. Making him pay only if he fails to
>   think like a single owner—that is, making him pay only if he doesn’t build
>   the fence, and it’s found that the fence would have paid for itself **in the**
>   broken windows it would have prevented—probably would do it, too.
>   That would be called liability for negligence.

Source: p 53, The Legal Analyst, Ward Farnsworth

I guess that here, **in the** = by means/reason of. In other words, the fence would've prevented the broken windows and the cost of fence is less than or equal to that of the windows.

Is this right? If so, please explain more about the use of **in the** here? Is there a term for it?

Comment: I think it's better to group *in* with *paid* and *the* with *broken windows* where they belong. The preposition *in* is used to indicate how to pay. One common expression of *pay in* is *pay in cash*. You can find both *pay for* and *pay in* in Macmillan Dictionary: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pay.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

The word for this is *English*. It's simply one of the uses of the word *in*, and not a very uncommon one:

> In ancient civilizations, people had no currency, they would pay in sheep.

(This is not true.)

> Samsung paid the fine to Apple in coins.

(This is [also not true](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/blog/2012/aug/29/apple-samsung-trucks-nickels-fake).)